# Help with using "Quality" in a plural sentence

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, plural-forms

Please help me to understand & explain the correct one among the following sentences:

1. Quality of the products is good.
2. Quality of the products are good.
3. Qualities of the products are good.

Answer (score 1):

1 is correct - "quality" as a mass noun refers to how good something is, and the products being of "good quality" means they're simply good - unspoiled, without defects, etc.

3 is also technically correct, but very unnatural and I wouldn't accept it. It uses "quality" as a countable noun to mean "a particular attribute of the product" and describes them as "good". Naturally, though, you would both specify the type of qualities you're referring to (eg. "aphrodisiac qualities") and pair them with a different adjective (eg. "strong").

2 is just ungrammatical - "quality" (singular) cannot be paired with "are", which refers to plural nouns.